# Move Bokeh y-axis ticks from default left hand side to right hand side of plot

Tags: plot, bokeh

I have a Bokeh line plot of financial data and need to see the y-axis tick marks and price values on the right hand side of the plot. Can anyone please tell me how this may be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `y_axis_location="right"` to `figure`.